# Any reasons to not go paperless at work?

Tags: work-environment, documentation

I'm considering going paperless at work. Just keep notes electronically, using a tablet. Anyone else done this? Any reason to keep a notebook, file cabinet for projects this day and age?

Engineering field.

Comment: That is going to depend on what type of work you do as going paperless in some fields is a lot easier than others.

Comment: Would you clarify what is meant by points about evolution?

Comment: Question: will any notes you keep on your tablet be needed for patent applications or other sorts of formal processes? If so, you may want to ask somebody about how to handle the sorts of evidentiary things you get from paper engineering notebooks.

Comment: You sound like the company is yours. You have a boss? If you have a boss and the boss insists that  you must keep a paper notebook. Do you say no? If you say no, are you ready to quit?

Comment: What if they insist we go paperless, any reasonable reason not to?

Comment: If they insist you go paperless, then you go paperless. You work for your company. Paperless or not is your company's policy. You can advise your boss to go paperless, but, ultimately, it's their decision, not yours. You got it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Any reason to keep a notebook, file cabinet for projects this day and age?

Yes, it will depend on:

- *The kind of work you do*: Some jobs still require to keep physical, paper copies of things. This is specially true for accountants, legal jobs, tax records, etc.. Many jobs now days could still require papers at least to some degree.
- *Company Culture:* Some companies require (by politics, handbook, etc.) to have paper copies of things. Or to send written letters for some procedures (which have to be stored somehow). Sometimes the receipts you get are printed in paper, and it would be wise to have those organized. And also, some companies may be a bit more "old-school" and expect their workers to at least write down notes on a notebook or paper, or use such means for drafts, drawings, brainstorms, etc..
- *Personal preference:* Some people (like myself) prefer to have things written in paper or notebook. This could be for various reasons, but in my case it's because of the ease of writing, drafting and sharing, compared to doing all that with some digital tool.
- *External factors:* Perhaps you and your whole company goes paper-less... but even though, other companies you interact with may not, and eventually some of their output may be in printed paper. This has to be kept somewhere in your paper-less company, and here is where cabinets come to the rescue.

> Any good tips about backing up, securing files if going fully paperless

There are *repositories and tools*, say Google Drive with their Docs, where you can save your notes and have it backed up and linked to your account. Personally, I also use tools like Asana, and there I write comments on the things and tasks I have to do.

Or, if you prefer to write them on Notepad or your preferred text editor, then doing regular backups is the way. This can be done by doing backup to some external drive or to your cloud (say Dropbox).

Comment: Indeed, the kind of work you do is important. I do a lot of design work. Paper and pen is far more comfortable when I'm designing a program.

Comment: I keep a notebook but also write up all my notes into Microsoft OneNote which is a fully collaborative tool that allows you to easily share and edit notes as a team, it reduced the amount of paper note taking we did dramatically.

Answer (score 4):

Quite apart from what's already mentioned, there's the data security issue.

Unless the company supplies the tablet you might not even be allowed to use it to keep notes of your work and meetings on it because such is a potentially very serious data leak. Not just a problem when it comes to possible industrial espionage, but it might be a crime depending on the data in question (e.g. in Europe if you did this on a personal device you are likely violating the GDPR depending on the data involved, even if it's just the name of a contact for a customer that you write down in your notes).

So whatever you do, take it up with your superiors and your company's data security officer at the very least.